# How do I shield my wifi from other users. I have changed my password but my Neighbour continues to use my wi fi

Tags: windows

despite me having a good password my neighbour uses my wi fi signal somehow. How can I block this so he cannot trace my signal

Comment: What, exactly, makes you so sure he’s on your network?

Answer (score 1):

Simplest option is to disable `Allow Broadcast of Name (SSID)` in your router.

After that;

1. Speak to them?
2. Set up some MAC address filtering
3. Use WPA2-PSK (AES)

Comment: MAC address filtering can be spoofed, but it's a fairly strong method for securing a network, especially if there are few attached devices.

Comment: If you down-voted this, please leave a comment as to why. Random unwarranted downvote is unwarranted.

Answer (score 0):

Besides, the other good answers, another thing along with using WPA2-PSK with AES is to disable WPS , which has not been mentioned !! And keep router firmware updated too.

Comment: WPS requires physical access to the router in order to establish the connection. I suspect that such access is not being permitted by the OP to the neighbor.